# How can an asterisk be found in a string using InStr function?

Tags: vba, excel

Microsoft documentation specifies to use `"~*"` to search for `"*"` in a string. `"~*"` and `"[*]"` don't work.

String expression being searched:
"Balık yağı, balık unu, yaş meyve, kuru meyve, sucuk pastırma, nebati yağ, süt ve süt mamulleri imalatında kullanılan iktisadi kıymetler ve özel araç gereçler *"

```
If InStr(1, WS.Cells(intRow, 6).Value, "~*", vbTextCompare) > 0 then
    'Additional code here
End If
```

This code can not find asterisk character.

Comment: This question is an instance of my stupidity but of course I thank for upvotes :-) I had used the statement which is the condition of if statement in the question without tilde in an complex logical statement and I had not understand that the false result had come from another component of that logical statement; so ı had thought that the correct writing is wrong by mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

get rid of `~` for `*` you dont need anything special.

```
Sub testss()

    Dim str As String

    str = "test*name"

    '/ Returns 0
    MsgBox InStr(1, str, "~*", vbTextCompare)

    '/ Returns 5
    MsgBox InStr(1, str, "*", vbTextCompare)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

`~*` is used to find `*` in `Range.Find` and `Range.Replace` (same in Excel's Find and Replace dialogs).

You can also use `InStrRev` to search in reverse order starting from the end of the string.

The [`Like` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator) can also be used with `[*]` to check if a string ends with `*` :

```
If WS.Cells(intRow, 6) Like "*[*]" Then
```